# Quick question on freeCodeCamp/JavaScript Basics Course

Tags: javascript

Here is the assingment:
https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/freecodecamp-challenge-guide-profile-lookup/18259

The question is why is my solution not working? To be exact, I cannot see the difference and really want to see it.

My solution:

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line
    for (let i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
      
      if (contacts[i].firstName===name){
        if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
          return contacts[i][prop];
        }else{
          return "No such property"
        }
      }else{    // <---the difference is here, in the solution there is no else.
        return "No such contact"  //<--- and the return is placed outside the for loop.
      }
    }  
  // Only change code above this line
}
```

The (right) solution 1 :

```
function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  for (let x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++) {
    if (contacts[x].firstName === name) {
      if (contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contacts[x][prop];
      } else {
        return "No such property";
      }
    }
  }
  return "No such contact";
}
```

Thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution returns "No such contact" if the *first* contact does not match. You never examine the contacts after the first, because you return already during the first execution of the `for` loop.

The correct solution returns "No such contact" only after the `for` loop has examined all contacts without finding a match.

Answer (score 0):

Because, you return value in the loop. You have to iterate over all values and if the all values do not fulfill the condition `contacts[x].firstName === name`  you return your message `No such contact` .

Example array: [{ firstName: 'John' }, { firstName: "Bob" }]
Example enter value: 'Bob'

Your solution will return: `No such contact`. It because you stop your loop in `else` block and return message `No such contact` . Note: return statement will stop your loop and return value.

Freecodecamp solution iterate values and **after loop** (if conditions are not met) they return message